# Apple Passes in Wallet don't update on push notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, passbook

I've got a problem with the integration of Apple push notifications for Apple Wallet with my web service.

What works:

- Endpoints (as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html);
- Passes are valid, they work with an iPhone, registering, manual update, unregistering, etc. seem to work, no errors from the logs of my server;
- The response from "Getting the Latest Version of a Pass" endpoint has the "Last-Modified" header.

Then I update a pass on the server. When I try to send a push notification nothing happens.

I did some debug, APN Server (https://api.push.apple.com:443) returns code 200 with an empty body and non-empty "apns-id" header. This looks OK (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html).

BUT! There are neither notifications nor an updated pass in Wallet on my iPhone.

When I do manual update, the pass updates and an update notification shows.

I cannot get what I did wrong...

P.S. I use https://github.com/mdigger/apns for making requests to the APNS.

Comment: What certificate are you using for the APNS connection?

Comment: I am using this cert: Apple Push Services: [...]; Identity: Apple Push Services: [...]; Verified by: Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority; Expires: XX/XX/18

Comment: That's your issue - you need to be using the Pass Type ID Certificate to connect to APNS.

Comment: When I download the Pass Type ID Certificate, it is .cer - but it seems I need PEM for the APNS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When connecting to APNS for Wallet updates, you need to connect with the same Pass Type ID Certificate that was used to sign the pass.

See the section:

> **Your Server Sends a Push Notification When Something Changes**

in the [wallet documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW1).

> Your server sends the following pieces of information:
>
> - The pass type identifier (in the certificate)
> - The push token (in the communication to the Apple Push Notification service)

Comment: Is there any way to use the http APNs to update passes? or we can only use the binary api trought "gateway.push.apple.com" port 2195?